# Heranca de Proprieade UserControl Para Form VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

Como faço para um form herdar as mesmas propriedades de um user control, ao arrastar do controlbox para o form?

Exemplo: Criei um UserControl com `FormBorderStyle = none`, compilei e gerei a DLL dentro do visual studio, adicionei esse novo controle no meu toolbox, e adicionei ao Form. Ao arrastar do toolbox queria que já definisse que este Form vai ter `FormBorderStyle = none`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ParentForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```